# What is wrong with this bifurcation plot?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

I am trying to plot the bifurcation diagram based on the steady-state values of the following ODE:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x(1-x)-rx$$
I take the right hand side $f(x) = x(1-x)-rx$ and I find the fixed points of $g(x) = f(x)+x$ which will give me the zeros of $f(x)$ hence the steady state points of the ODE.
I find the fixed points of $g(x)$ using the method introduce in [here](https://ipython-books.github.io/121-plotting-the-bifurcation-diagram-of-a-chaotic-dynamical-system/) and by the recursive relationship $x_{n+1}=g(x_n)$.
I get the following diagram:
[image]

As you can see I am getting negative values. But this is a population growth model and shouldn't be negative. In fact, I give values of r>3 to the ODE and the dynamics go to zero but never negative. I very much appreciate it if you can help me with this.

Comment: The fixed-point iteration has nothing to do with the differential equation. You always have two equilibrium points at $x=0$ and $x=1-r$ that cross for $r=1$. Nothing interesting happens.

Comment: Thank for the reply. I simply think saying it has nothing to do with the ODE is a bit strong. As you can see the behavior you explained happens at the beginning. The fixed point iteration is just a way to get around the use of fsolve or fzeros many times. The fixed points of g(x) are analytically the roots of f(x) hence the equilibrium.